# Get max axis value from MS Charts C#.NET

Tags: annotations, customization

I banged and banged my head on this one for a while and I figured someone else may have this problem down the line. I'm posting my full issue and resolution to those who come later, and to offer a spot for any improvements/simplifications if anyone finds one.

Issue was I am trying to paint VerticalLineAnnotations on my ChartArea. I do not want to anchor it to any data points but merely anchor it to an X axis based on which ChartArea I send in. In my annotation constructor I was trying to set AnchorX.

```
double maxdate = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum;
double mindate = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;

//use inputdata to find where relative spot is.
if(DateTime.TryParse(date, out ddate)) {
    AnchorX = (ddate.ToOADate()) / (maxdate - mindate);
}
```

I kept getting the mins and maxs to return as NaN, which I found out means the ChartArea will manage itself and set its own max/mins. This was all pre-painting.

I tried post painting but then everytime it painted, it would add annotation, then do postpaint again and infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an event that lets me do this. The Customize() event solved this issue.

```
private void chart_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        PaintAnnotations();
    }
```

Now immediately before the painting happens, data seems to be loaded and max and mins are already set by this point and I can get values back in the code from above.

Hope this can save someone the hours that I lost!